# How to add youtube search to android app

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

how can i add youtube search to my android app like applications like iTube and other music listening app.

I was trying to find anything about it in some api documentation but wasn't able to .

I would be glad if anybody could point me to the right place.

Answer (score 1):

you may use youtube data API v3 to achieve this. use search API like this way

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=eminem&type=video&key=<key>
```

You can play with parameters to get what you actually need. You also need an API key from https://console.developers.google.com/.

Comment: How is the display of the search results working? Since so far i've been working with xml design is there something like html iframe or its dynamic display of xml objects?

Answer (score 0):

The search bar is not built-in. You have to write your own implementation of the search UI. So in android it would be something like a [search dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html):

> The search dialog is a UI component that's controlled by the Android
>   system. When activated by the user, the search dialog appears at the
>   top of the activity, as shown in figure 1. The Android system controls
>   all events in the search dialog. When the user submits a query, the
>   system delivers the query to the activity that you specify to handle
>   searches. The dialog can also provide search suggestions while the
>   user types.

Then, it's up to you to use the text input from that dialog to the 'q' parameter in Youtube API search.